# What video format works best for a website designed for mobile phones?

Tags: html, video, mobile-phones

I am going to be working on designing a mobile-phone friendly version of a client's website.  I have done the research on how to build it, bu, as we have a few videos on it, I need to know what video formats would work best when a phone accesses the site.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Any format which is most widely used in mobile phones. Most high end phones play flash files (and 3gp, mp4 etc), Others support 3gp and mp4.

So I would go for 3gp as it will be supported by most of the phones.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you would likely do well to invest in [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) and then convert something like an MP3 or MP4 on the server to the media that is necessary for the mobile phone. In other words, don't just serve up 3gp or mp4 and assume. Note, though, I'm still learning this.